# Is the W3 Total Cache plugin a good choice for WordPress MultiSite?

Tags: multisite, plugin-w3-total-cache, cache

I heard that many people had issues with [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) on a WordPress MultiSite install. And then I see this on the plugin page:

> Compatible up to: 3.2.1
>
> Last Updated: 2011-8-26

Seeing that I'm running on WordPress MultiSite Version 3.4.1 and that it's been over a year since the last plugin update, I'm really wondering if this plugin is a good choice for me.

Or should I use [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/) with [WP Minify](https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-minify/) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

W3 Total Cache is a GREAT option! One thing to keep in mind is that you need to individually work with each site for the settings - there is not a global settings area (yet). The next version is said to have this built-in. If you need this "right now", then WP Super cache does this and is a great option, if you can hold out for a little bit, then W3 Total Cache would be my personal recommendation. Thanks!

Comment: it has multi-site support now

Answer (score 3):

In short yes ... I'm using it on my own multisite with about 7 subsites and its working fine.

If you have many users, then this probably a good choice as it can be activated per blog.

It also has a great deal of integration for CDN, minify and and control over the caching headers.

Comment: Definitely YES!

Answer (score 3):

We use it with great success with about 2 million page views of traffic monthly and it relieves a great deal of stress from our servers. As others have mentioned, its configurability is also a plus allowing you to control which sites use it or not.

Our experience is using IIS so your mileage may vary if you're using Apache or ngix